# Slider, uno se pone en la posición del otro

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, bootstrap-4

Buenas tengo un carrousel que estoy creando.

Las funciones del atrás y el siguiente me funcionan, pero necesito que al seleccionar la siguiente siempre se me ponga en la posición de la morada y la otra en la posición de la verde. Si es posible me gustaria ponerle alguna transición para que no quede tan plano.

Pero de este modo siempre me desaparece una por el display y no cambian de posición. Alguna sugerencia? no se bien como crearlo, gracias.

```js
var proceso;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var actualIndice = 0;
  var objetos = $('.contenedor > div');
  var numObjetos = objetos.length;

  function cambiarImagen() {
    var imagen = objetos.eq(actualIndice);
    objetos.hide();
    imagen.css('display', 'block');
  }
  //proceso = setInterval(function() {
  //  actualIndice += 1;
  //  if (actualIndice > (numObjetos - 1)) {
  //    actualIndice = 0;
  //  }
  //  cambiarImagen();
  //}, 3000);
  $('.siguiente').click(function() {
    limpiarIntervalo();
    actualIndice += 1;
    if (actualIndice > (numObjetos - 1)) {
      actualIndice = 0;
    }
    cambiarImagen();
  });
  $('.anterior').click(function() {
    limpiarIntervalo();
    actualIndice -= 1;
    if (actualIndice < 0) {
      actualIndice = numObjetos - 1;
    }
    cambiarImagen();
  });
});

function limpiarIntervalo() {
  window.clearInterval(proceso);
}
```

```css
.cardsTwo {
    background: #9124a4;
    position: absolute;
    top: -114%;
    border-radius: 20px;
   
}
.padCardsTwo {
    padding: 43px 25px;
}
.cardsTwo h3 {
    font-size: 2.9rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
.cardsTwo h4 {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #ffeb3b;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
.cardsTwo p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 16%;
}
.btnResDiVer {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    background: #00ce80;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 11px 22px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #00ce80;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: block;
}
.btnResDiVer2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 11px 22px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px #eeafe1;
}
.anterior {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 50px;
    top: 206px;
    left: 40px;
}
.siguiente {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 50px;
    top: 206px;
    left: 854px;
}
.cardsTwo2 {
    background: #02cd80;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left: 179px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 515px;
}
.btnResDiVer2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 11px 22px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px #eeafe1;
}
.btnResDiVer {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    background: #00ce80;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 11px 22px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #00ce80;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="contenedor">
  <div>
    <div class="cardsTwo2">
      <div class="padCardsTwo">
        <h3>Láser de diodo</h3>
        <h4>Desde 10€</h4>
        <p>Depilate con nuestro láser de diodo<br>sin bonos ni ataduras<br>¡Así de fácil!</p>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer">Reserva tu cita</a>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer2">Ver nuestras tarifas</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="col-9 offset-md-2 cardsTwo">
      <div class="padCardsTwo">
        <h3>Láser de diodo</h3>
        <h4>Desde 10€</h4>
        <p>Depilate con nuestro láser de diodo<br>sin bonos ni ataduras<br>¡Así de fácil!</p>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer">Reserva tu cita</a>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer2">Ver nuestras tarifas</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="anterior">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
</div>
<div class="siguiente">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Usas bootstrap 3?

Comment: Hola! @Ruslan López no, utilizo bootstrap 4

Comment: tal vez quieras agregar algo de tu css en el snippet, das click en editar,  y bajas hasta el snippet ejecutable, te aparecerá un enlace que dice editar snippet, así se parecerá más a la imágen que pones.

Comment: No te entendi bien! Quieres que modifique la pregunta con el css??

Comment: sí, creo que tu problema es de css y ese código no lo compartiste, adicionalmente deberías de realizar el recorrido para que aprendas a usar los snippets

Comment: Buenas @RuslanLópez perdona por la tardanza en contestar, pero me e tenido que poner en otras cosas, he colocado los snippets pero no se ven como en la foto, también he puesto los css por si puedes ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: para este caso en particular creo que es muy necesario la parte verificable del [mcve] o podrían votar para cerrar la pregunta como fuera de tema porque "Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos."

Comment: entiendo, pero copie el código tal cual lo tengo y a mi se me visualiza tal y como esta en la foto

Comment: tal vez se deba a una versión personalizada de las dependencias, deberías de probar las que te sugerí en el snippet

Comment: creo que estan las mismas que tu me pusiste

Comment: no creas, asegúrate, y revisa la página en tu navegador, alli salen listadas todas las hojas de estilo usadas, a veces interactuan mal.

Comment: como edito el snippet?

Comment: acá la documentación: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%C3%A9-es-stack-snippet

Comment: Listo! @RuslanLópez ya he conseguido mostrarlo más o menos como toca, pero al menos para que veas lo que necesito esta

Comment: ahora agrega a la pregunta como debería quedar tu solución ideal que yo aún no lo llego a entender